# Объясните, пожалуйста, на уровне школы: от каких главных слов задаются вопросы ко всем видам придаточных в сложноподчиненных предложениях

Tags: спп, сложное-предложение

Если можно, то лучше подробно, т. к. с этим периодически возникают проблемы. Возможно, есть схемы, или вы можете предоставить ссылки на информативные сайты именно по этой теме.

Comment: Уточните, что вы называете "главными словами". Лучше всего - ссылку на формулировку в учебнике или пособии. И примеры предложений, которые у вас вызывают затруднения. А вопросы задаются от тех слов в главном предложении, которые объясняет или раскрывает придаточное. Это если "на уровне школы".

Answer (score 1):

**Классификация СПП**

Классификация сложноподчиненных предложений (СПП) изучается в 9 классе, причем в учебнике дается школьный вариант, согласно которому  СПП делятся на три группы: **определительные, изъяснительные и обстоятельственные**. Это упрощенная классификация,  поэтому  **для составления схем**  желательно использовать дополнительную информацию, которую проходят в вузах. Там все СПП делятся **на две принципиально разные группы**: (1) нерасчлененные с местоименной связью и  (2) расчлененные с союзной связью.

**Расчлененные СПП (союзная связь)**

К этому виду  относится большинство СПП с **обстоятельственными придаточными** (кроме придаточных места, образа действия и степени). Они похожи на сложносочиненные предложения (ССП) и отличаютсятолько видом союза (подчинительный или сочинительный). Схемы тоже похожи, только подчинительный союз  включается в состав придаточного , а сочинительный союз стоит между предложениями.
Например, сравним такие предложения: Наступает зима, и птицы улетают на юг. Когда наступает зима, птицы улетают на юг. На схемах изображаются только союзы): [     ], и  [     ]. (Когда…), [     ].

Вопрос задается от сказуемого, как для обычного обстоятельства: улетают когда?  Но на  схеме не обозначается слово, от которого задается вопрос, так как придаточное относится ко всему  предложению (к его предикативной основе подлежащее + сказуемое).

**Нерасчлененные СПП**

Это изъяснительные и определительные придаточные, а также  некоторые обстоятельственные придаточные. В таких СПП придаточное относится **к опорному слову в главной предложении** (присловная связь). Также для них характерна **местоименно-соотносительная связь**: указательное местоимение в главном предложении и  союзное слово в придаточном предложении (такой – какой, тот – что, так – как, там – где).

На схеме изображаются: **опорные слова, указательные и союзные слова.**  Для **изъяснительных** СПП опорными (главными)   являются слова со значением речи  и восприятия (глаголы, наречия, существительные: сказал что? рад чему? видно что? сообщение о чем?). Для **определительных** СПП опорным словом является определяемое существительное, задается вопрос «какой». Для остальных видов СПП вопрос задается в зависимости от того, с каким словом связано указательное местоимение.

Примеры:

**1. Придаточные определительные**

Опорным словом является существительное. Союзные слова: который, какой, чей, что,  где, куда, откуда, когда. Указательные слова: тот, такой.
Он имел такой успех, какой бывает не часто. Схема: […такой успех], (какой…).  Успех какой?

Другие примеры: Трудности только усиливали то радостное волнение, в котором находился Арсений. Были такие люди, которые его боялись. Облако превратилось в тучу, которая закрыла всё небо.

Замена союзного слова «который»: Это дом, где (= в котором) мы жили раньше. Мы поднялись на холмик, откуда (= с которого) начиналась тропинка. В летние дни, когда (= в которые)  город изнывает от жажды, здесь довольно прохладно.

**2. Придаточные образа действия**

Здесь всё сохранилось так, как было раньше. Схема […сохранилось так ], (как…).  Вопрос задается от глагола: сохранилось как?

**3. Придаточные степени:**

На улице так холодно, как бывает только зимой. Схема:  […так холодно ], (как…).  Вопрос задается от наречия:  в какой степени холодно?

**4. Придаточные местоименно-определительные**

В этом случае в качестве опорного слова используется местоимение, которое в главном предложении может быть подлежащим, сказуемым, дополнением.

Возьми то, что тебе нравится. Схема […то ], (что…).  Возьми что? Что именно?  Придаточное раскрывает значение местоимения. Тот,  кто приходил, оставил записку.   Кто? Кто именно?

**4. Придаточные места**

Все обернулись туда, откуда выскочили гончие. Схема:  […туда ], (откуда…).
Обернулись куда? Вопрос задается от глагола, но на схеме  обозначается только местоименная пара.

**5. Придаточное времени**

Начнем тогда, когда всё будет готово. Схема:  […тогда], (когда…).
При наличии местоименной связи "тогда – когда" СПП относят к нерасчлененному типу.  Начнем когда? Вопрос задается от глагола, но на схеме обозначается только местоименная пара.